# deleting node using free

Tags: c++, memory

When I use `delete p` in `deleteAlternateNodes()`, I am getting a runtime error. But, when I use `free(p)`, the code works fine. What is the reason for this?

`Node` contains the data and a pointer to the next node:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node * next;
    
    Node(int data){
        this -> data = data;
        this -> next = NULL;
    }
    
    ~Node() {
        if(next) {
            delete next;
        }
    }
};
```

This is the function in which I am facing error.

```cpp
void deleteAlternateNodes(Node *head) {
    //Write your code here
    Node *p =head;
    Node *q =NULL;
    if(p->next == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        q=p;
        p=p->next;
        q->next = p->next;
        
        free(p);
        p = q->next;
    }
}

Node* takeinput() {
    int data;
    cin >> data;
    Node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    while(data != -1){
        Node *newNode = new Node(data);
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else{
            tail -> next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        cin >> data;
    }
    return head;
}
```

`print()` is just a function to print the nodes.

```cpp
int main() {
    Node *head = takeinput();
    deleteAlternateNodes(head);
    print(head);
    delete head;
    return 0;
}
```

Please, also differentiate between `free()` and `delete`.

Comment: you cannot `free` a `new`-ed object

Comment: Calling the `Node` destructor recursively is a *really bad* idea, especially if the list has a lot of nodes in it. You really need an iterative loop instead of a recursive loop. But you can't implement an iterative loop inside the `Node` destructor, so you should create a separate `List` class that manages a list of `Node`s, and then have that `List` be responsible for freeing any `Node`s it creates. Then it can use an iterative loop.

Comment: but when i use free code is running but on using delete i am getting run time error

Comment: @Abhinav1036 That is because your code logic is simply managing the nodes incorrectly, not because it is creating/destroying them incorrectly. You need to fix your logic, not change `delete` to `free()`. You are treating the wrong thing,

Comment: Changing `delete` to `free` does not fix the cause of your runtime error.  At best, it hides the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

Your `deleteAlternateNodes()` function is simply broken, and is causing *undefined behavior*, which is why your code is crashing.

Specifically:

- it is not handling the case where `head` is NULL for an empty list.
- inside the `while` loop, when `p` reaches the last node in the list, the loop sets `p` to NULL and then immediately afterwards tries to access `p->next`.
- when `delete`'ing a `Node`, you are not clearing its `next` pointer first.  So, when the 1st loop iteration destroys the 2nd node in the list, your `~Node()` destructor **recursively destroys all of the remaining nodes in the list**!  But your loop doesn't know the list has been destroyed, so it tries to continue accessing the now-destroyed nodes, hence the runtime error.
- switching to `free()` *appears* to fix that problem, because `free()` will not invoke the `~Node()` destructor, like `delete` does.  However, now you have introduced a different kind of *undefined behavior*, because an object created with `new` MUST be destroyed with `delete`, not `free()`.  It is *undefined behavior* to mix memory managers - ie, using `new` with `free()`, `malloc()` with `delete`, etc.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void deleteAlternateNodes(Node *head) {
    Node *p = head, *q;
    while ((p != NULL) && (p->next != NULL)) {
        q = p->next;
        p->next = q->next;
        q->next = NULL;
        delete q;
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/0ngoXF)

That being said, I can't stress enough why destroying `Node`s *recursively* is a **really bad** idea.  Not only because of the problem explained above, but also because if the list has a lot of nodes in it then you can overflow the call stack, causing a different kind of crash.

When destroying nodes in a loop, you really need an iterative loop rather than a recursive loop. But you can't implement an iterative loop inside the `~Node()` destructor itself, so you should instead implement a separate `List` class that creates and destroys the list of `Node`s. Then it can use an iterative loop when destroying nodes in the list.

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    
    Node(int data) : data(data), next(NULL) {}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node *head, *tail;

public:
    LinkedList() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}

    // disabling these just for demonstration purposes,
    // but you really should implement them properly...
    LinkedList(const LinkedList&) = delete;
    LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList&) = delete;
    //

    ~LinkedList() {
        Node *p = head, *n;
        while (p) {
            n = p->next;
            delete p;
            p = n;
        }
    }

    Node* add(int data) {
        Node *newNode = new Node(data);
        if (!head) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        if (tail) {
            tail->next = newNode;
        }
        tail = newNode;
        return newNode;
    }
    
    void print() const {
        // print the nodes as needed ...
    }

    void deleteAlternateNodes() {
        Node *p = head, *q;
        while ((p != NULL) && (p->next != NULL)) {
            q = p->next;
            p->next = q->next;
            if (tail == q) tail = p;
            delete q;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList ll;

    int data;
    while ((cin >> data) && (data != -1)) {
        ll.add(data);
    }

    ll.print();
    ll.deleteAlternateNodes();
    ll.print();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/QV17ps)

Comment: sir can u tell me free and delete work. What happen at the backend when we use free and delete.

Comment: destroying Nodes recursively is a really bad idea.  . sir why the stack get overflow when we are destroying the nodes

Answer (score 2):

If memory is allocated with `new` it **MUST** be released with `delete`. This is a requirement of the language. using `free()` is technically undefined behavior (i.e. your program is not valid).

By using `free()` you are releasing it to the wrong memory management routines.

A tangibly noticeable missing side effect with `free()` is that it does not call destructors.

What happens here:

```
if(p->next == NULL)
{
    return;
}
```

If your list is empty?

This line looks funny:

```
 q->next = p->next;


  Before:

      p          q
     ########    ######## 
     # next # -> # next # ->  // null
     ########    ########  
                           
  After 
      p          q
     ########    ######## 
     # next # -> # next # -| 
     ######## |  ########  |
              |            |
              --------------
```

You should draw out a list of three items. Then draw what this line does to your list.

This line also looks wrong:

```
 p = q->next;
```

Comment: sir but my code is working on using free and getting run time error on using delete

Comment: @Abhinav1036 It is not working. It is just not crasing.

Comment: sir how to check whether our code logic is correct or the code is wrong but it just not crashing

Comment: @Abhinav1036: When your code has Undefined behavior (calling free on memory allocated with new) the code is invalid. It can do anything (that includes looking like it works).

Comment: sir can u check this site even here they are using free https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-alternate-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: @Abhinav1036 That is broken code. You should stop using that site.

Comment: sir can u reccomend some site and what to do to make my code correct

Comment: @Abhinav1036 that site is using `malloc()` to allocate nodes, so it is correct to use `free()` to deallocate them. That is not the case in your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see `new Node()`